# Why does not the weighted sum of gamma distribution come from weighted gamma variables?

Tags: gamma-distribution, mixture-distribution

If $Z\sim 0.3\Gamma(\alpha _1,\beta _1)+0.7\Gamma (\alpha _2,\beta_2)$, why isn't $Z=0.3X_1+0.7X_2$? $X_1\sim\Gamma(\alpha _1,\beta _1)$ and $X_2\sim\Gamma(\alpha _2,\beta _2)$?

Comment: related question about Gaussians [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309154/intuition-for-why-sum-of-gaussian-rvs-is-different-from-gaussian-mixture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up very different things.

A probability density function like you are describing with $P(Z) = 0.3 P(X) + 0.7 P(Y)$ is likely a **mixture distribution** (see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution)). That means the value of Z is realized first picking whether to choose from the distribution of X (30% probability) or Y  (70%) at random and then picking a value from the chosen distribution.

Secondly, if you look at **sums of random variables** like $Z=X+Y$ the resulting probability density is given as the *convolution* of the individual distributions. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions). Now for sums of random gamma variables the sum is a little more tricky. It is easy if you have the same scale factor, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/generic-sum-of-gamma-random-variables)